# how to remove everything after specific text with xpath

Tags: xpath, telegram

I am trying to setup a Telegram Instant View for a website. 
i have something like this code and want to remove everything after "remove from here" text

```
<p> sample text <p> test</p> remove from here <p>test text</p>   </p>
```

how can i access every text/nodes after this specific text ("remove from here") and remove them?

**Update:**
i want to have this result:

```
<p> sample text <p> test</p> remove from here</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean *remove text with xpath*? `XPath` cannot be used to remove something. Could you clarify desired output?

Comment: i updated my question and add my desired output

Answer (score 0):

> how can i access every text/nodes after this specific text

You can use `following-sibling::*` from XPath to access the nodes on the same level after the one you selected.

Then use `@remove` function from the Instant View DSL:

```
$selected_node: //*[self::text() and normalize-space()="remove from here"]
@remove: $selected_node/following-sibling::*
```

You may want to be more specific with the `$selected_node`. Depending on your needs, you may want to add predicates to remove only certain types of the following siblings, for example: `following-sibling::*[self::node() or self::text()]`.